# Can I use custom elements and attributes as valid HTML?

Tags: html, css, less

Can I use this (custom elements, custom attributes) on (for examples) **IE 9** with this CSS? Is this valid? What are the negatives?

I want to have more readable code... without divs.

## HTML

```
<row center>
  <column number="6">A</column>
</row>
```

## CSS / LESS

```
row {
  background: #444;
  display: flex;

  &[center] {
    justify-content: center;
  }

  column {
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;

    &[number="6"] {
      padding: 1rem;
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont think there are any major negatives. What's the purpose of using custom elements?

Comment: The negatives are that some browsers may not recognise them leading to unpredictable behaviour. A better question is "What are the overriding reasons for using them over more traditional elements?"

Comment: I want to have more readable code... without divs

Comment: are you using a library or framework to create custom elements?

Comment: I using pure HTML, CSS... without lib or framework

Comment: You can't write custom elements when you're not using a library or framework. Take a look at https://angularjs.org/, Angular, for example, is a framework that supports custom elements by using directives

Comment: What is your DOCTYPE declaration? Do you care about writing valid code?

Comment: @NickSpriet he can write custom elements if he types them into a text editor, it's just not a great idea

Comment: you should maybe use `table` in this case

Answer (score 2):

The case against custom elements has been made by other answers. As an alternative to this idea, [HTML 5 has a number of new elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html). These include `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<figure>`, `<header>`, `<nav>`, and `<section>`. Using these elements should make your page layout semantically meaningful, save you from puzzling over a sea of `<div>` and `<span>` elements, and be understood by modern browsers.

Comment: Their is others semantic elements very useful: list (`ul`/`ol`/`li`, `dl`/`dt`/`dd`), `table`, `main`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Making up your own markup language:

- May conflict with additional features added to HTML in the future (at least if you tell the browser it is HTML with a `Content-Type: text/html` HTTP header).
- Won't be properly understood by user agents which you can't completely override with CSS (such as screen readers, text browsers and search engines).
- Won't be understood by other developers who may have to maintain your code in the future.
- Can't use an HTML validator for a cheap, basic QA pass

Answer (score 1):

The W3C is developing a standard call [**Custom Elements**](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/), which allows authors to define their own elements. You can read about it here:

- [Custom Elements, defining new elements in HTML](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)

  > Custom Elements allow web developers to define new types of HTML
  >   elements. The spec is one of several new API primitives landing under
  >   the Web Components umbrella, but it's quite possibly the most
  >   important. Web Components don't exist without the features unlocked by
  >   custom elements:
  >
  > - Define new HTML/DOM elements
  > - Create elements that extend from other elements
  > - Logically bundle together custom functionality into a single tag
  > - Extend the API of existing DOM elements
- [Introduction to Custom Elements](http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-custom-elements/)

  > Custom Elements enable developers to create their own custom HTML
  >   tags, let them use those tags in their sites and apps, and enable
  >   easier component reuse.
- [W3C Custom Elements](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/)

  > Provide a way for Web developers to build their own, fully-featured
  >   DOM elements. Though it was long possible to create DOM elements with
  >   any tag names in HTML, these elements weren't very functional. By
  >   giving Web developers the means to both inform the parser on how to
  >   properly construct an element and to react to lifecycle changes of an
  >   element, the specification eliminates the need for
  >   DOM-as-a-render-view scaffolding that has to exist today in most web
  >   frameworks or libraries.

However, if your goal for today is to write more readable code, then consider sticking with standard HTML elements (or just `div` and `span` elements) and using `class` and `id` values for descriptions. You can be as descriptive as you like with classes and ids. See my answers here for guidance:

- [Default settings of unrecognized HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35689456/3597276)
- [Is there a standard method for naming classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31911732/3597276)
- [HTML5 ID Attribute Values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31773673/3597276)

Comment: Important note from that spec: *Publication as an Editor's Draft does not imply endorsement by the W3C Membership*

Comment: Other important note from that spec: *developers must convey the semantics using ARIA roles, states and properties* (which will probably break the author's goal of having simpler markup)

Comment: @quentin, *Custom Elements* (as I'm sure you know) is a part of HTML5 web components, which is aggressively being pursued and developed by W3C, Google and other big players. The goal is to make it available to all, so I'm not sure your characterization of *breaking the author's goal* of simplicity is valid. I think it will be accessible without much difficulty in the future.

Comment: @Quentin, And yes, I'm aware of the status of the spec. This line is similar to your citation: *This is a public copy of the editors’ draft. It is provided for discussion only and may change at any moment. Its publication here does not imply endorsement of its contents by W3C. Don’t cite this document other than as work in progress.* ~ from the [flexbox spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/).