# What are valid values for the class attribute in HTML?

Tags: html, class

When creating the **class** attributes for HTML elements, what rules are there for the value?

Comment: Search through the internet. Very basic.

Answer (score 1):

[HTML class Attribute Values](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_global_class.asp)

> Naming rules:
>
> - Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
> - Can be followed by: letters    (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_")
> - In HTML,    all values are case-insensitive

https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_global_class.asp

Comment: Are the class naming rules similar to id naming rules in HTML?

Comment: @SafeerAhmed, yes you're right, the same rules apply to HTML id Attribute https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_global_id.asp . "`id` -
 Specifies a unique id for the element. Naming rules:
Must contain at least one character
Must not contain any space characters
In HTML, all values are case-insensitive"

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these links:

1. [What is the standard naming convention for html/css ids and classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6028211/7088500)
2. [Is there a standard method for naming classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31911182/7088500)
3. [Naming convention](https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/)